# Remove string before slash

Tags: regex

I need help in regular expression
in string:

```
/Users/folder1/folder2/folder3/ololo/ImageName.png
```

I need to match:

```
ololo/ImageName.png
```

Comment: It seems like such a simple problem. Have you considered *not* using a complicated regex for that?

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
/([^/]+/[^/]+)$
```

you can review this [reference](http://www.regular-expressions.info/reference.html) about regexp

Comment: How about some googling?

Comment: @Sergey: sorry but I don't know objective-c so cannot help

Comment: so, thanks, I think this is also useful to me